# Change DMA memory content

Tags: stm32, dma, keil

I need to change the DMA content(the values of the memory) for my application(doing animation on ws2812b strips).

- DMA circular mode
- DMA with PWM generation

To further clarify, here's code for a single frame:

```
static uint8_t LEDbuffer[LED_FRAMES * LED_BUFFER_SIZE];

static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{
  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = (uint32_t)((SystemCoreClock / TIMER_CLOCK_FREQ) - 1);
  htim3.Init.RepetitionCounter = LED_BUFFER_SIZE + 1;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = TIMER_PERIOD - 1;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim3);

  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;


  HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_DMA(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1, (uint32_t *) LEDbuffer,
            LED_BUFFER_SIZE);
}
```

What I wish to do is change LEDbuffer on the go.

---

I've tried reconfiguring PWM and restarting DMA, but didn't work:

```
    HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_DMA(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1, (uint32_t *) LEDbuffer,
            LED_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Comment: It's not clear why you think you need to reconfigure the PWM and restart the DMA. You can change the values in your `LEDBuffer` whenever you like while the DMA is running.

Comment: @brhans Turns out directly changing `LEDbuffer` works. Should I delete the question? It is pretty stupid.